# Convert roman numerals to uppercase

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database where the field "description" has strings of different lengths with roman numbers inside (which sometimes start with capital letters). I'll show you a short example:

```
room xi construction
room construction Xx
street Xi
room street ii
etc..
```

How could I convert all Roman numerals to roman numerals in uppercase?

expected result:

```
room XI construction
room construction XX
street XI
room street II
etc..
```

I've searched everywhere but I can't find a script (working in mysql) that can find the Roman numeral inside the string without getting confused with the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not done in database itself.

Comment: maybe a regex would help?

Comment: how big are the number hundreds thousands ? and i and roman I will not be possible, you will have to find the rows and update manualy

Comment: And how are you supposed to distinguish actual words such as "I" and "MIX" from roman numerals?